# how to create sqlite database at fix location

Tags: cocoa, macos, fmdb

How can I create Sqlite database file at a fix location. I am using FMDB wrapper to create database file. I want to create the database file at the location I am entering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where do you want to storage your database?

`fmdb` makes it very easy by `FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmp.db"];`

you could just change `"/tmp/tmp.db"` to the location of your preference, maybe the application support folder.